# Including help file within MSI Installers

Tags: windows-installer

Desperately need a solution. I am trying to include an help file with software installer. So that after the software is successfully installed, the user will find the help file under the "Start" menu. I am not able to achieve this. I am using VS2010 setup project. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to add a shortcut file to your "Application Project" and then set the Build Action property to Content.

Then, in your "Setup project" you add the file from your "Application project" to the User's start menu folder.

To add the project output of the "Application project" to the "Setup project"

- In the File System Editor, click Application Folder.
- On the Action menu, point to Add, and then click Project Output.
- In the Add Project Output Group dialog box, click Primary output, and then click OK.
- In the File System Editor, click User's start menu folder.
- On the Action menu, point to Add, and then click Project Output.
- In the Add Project Output Group dialog box, click Content Files, and then click OK.

To actually create the shortcut see - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140443

If you get stuck this article should help - http://developingfor.net/2008/03/04/visual-studio-2008-setup-project-frustrations/